# Determine which words are anagrams of each other - Hackerrank latest question

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I got below question from Hackerrank but i haven't able to solve it getting some issue in dictionary below is my code in which i got error while running . could you please check and let me know where i messed up

Question

Given an array of words and an array of sentences, determine which words are anagrams of each other. Calculate how many sentences can be created by replacing any word with one of the anagrams.

Example wordSet = ['listen', 'silent, 'it', 'is'] sentence = 'listen it is silent' Determine that listen is an anagram of silent. Those two words can be replaced with their anagrams.

The four sentences that can be created are:

• listen it is silent    • listen it is listen    • silent it is silent     • silent it is listen

Function Description Complete the countSentences function in the editor below. countSentences has the following parameters: string wordSet[n]: an array of strings string sentences[m]: an array of strings Returns: int[]: an array of m integers that denote the number of sentences that can be formed from each sentence

Below is the code that i tried in c#( Working solution is avaliable in JAVA which i used as reference to make the code in C#.

Java Working code ref link https://leetcode.com/playground/dBCY7Rs4

static void Main(string[] args)
{

```
        String[] arr
            = { "cat", "dog", "tac", "god", "act" };
        printAnagrams(arr);


        String[] words = { "bats", "tabs", "in", "cat", "act" };
        String[] sentences = { "cat the bats", "in the act", "act tabs in" };
       
        int[] count = new int[1000];

        Dictionary<String, List<String>> map = new Dictionary<String, List<String>>();
        Dictionary<String, List<String>> mapToUse = new Dictionary<String, List<String>>();

        foreach (string word in words)
        { 
            char[] charArr = word.ToCharArray();
            Array.Sort(charArr);
            String sorted = new String(charArr);

            

            if (map.ContainsKey(sorted))
            {

                //
                List<String> list = map[sorted];
                list.Add(word);
                map.Add(sorted, list);
                mapToUse.Add(word, list);
            }
            else
            {

                //
                List<String> list = new List<String>();
                list.Add(word);
                map.Add(sorted, list);
                mapToUse.Add(word, list);
            }

        }
        int index = 0;


        foreach (String sentence in sentences)
        {
            int c = 1;
            String[] strArr = sentence.Trim().Split(' ');
            foreach (String str in strArr)
            {
                if (mapToUse.ContainsKey(str))
                {
                    List<String> list = mapToUse[str];
                    c = c * list.Count();
                }
            }
            count[index++] = c;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < count.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(count[i] + " ");
        }
    
}
```

Comment: You don't appear to have actually explained what your problem is. You've told us what you're trying to do and how you're trying to do it, but not what happens when you try it. "some issue in dictionary" is not an explanation.

Comment: sorry to miss that . in dictionary i am getting error like "an item with the same key has already been added"

Comment: if `map` contains `sorted` then you don't  want to do `map.Add(sorted, list);` as the list is already in the dictionary with that key.

Comment: Yes that fixed it thanks

Answer (score 0):

HackerRank Certification most important problem is string anagram, i provide that is solution in python -3 i hope the following anagram code is useful for many people for cracked the hhackerRank string anagram exam.

```
dictionary = [''.join(sorted(d)) for d in dictionary]
dic = {}
for d in dictionary:
    if d in dic:
        dic[d] += 1
    else:
        dic[d]=1
        
query = [''.join(sorted(q)) for q in query]
nl = []
for q in query:
    if q in dic:
        nl.append(dic[q])
    else:
        nl.append(0)
return nl
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**